# Drag an item underneath a list of div's

Tags: jquery

I have a draggable :

```
<ul>
    <li>Option 1</li>
</ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "li" ).draggable({
            connectToSortable: //I don't where what should be configured here
        });
    });
    </script>

<div></div>
<div></div>
//add item here
```

I'm attempting to drag 'Option 1' so that it will drag underneath the last div in a list of existing divs, how can this be enabled ? I think I need to somehow keep track of the list of divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me was to add a new div under the list of divs, add a css class this div and make it sortable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            revert: true
        });
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#sortable",
            helper: "clone",
            revert: "invalid"
        });
        $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
    });
    </script>
```